# Filter and sort nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array of objects, and each object has another array of objects that I would like to get filtered by a specific key value - for example, return only the object where **name: "jobs"**.

After that, I would like to sort all the objects in the companies array and return the one with the biggest score point for "jobs".

I am not sure what is the best way to approach this problem.

Here is the original array of objects:

```
        companies = [
         {
         about:"Dolore occaecat cillum."
         address:"Manhattan Court, 445"
         city:"Brecon, Massachusetts"
         email:"info@ziggles.info"
         id:0
         name:"Ziggles"
         phone:"+1 (944) 472-2911"
         postal_code:33
         project_number:2016823
         scores:[
           {
             name:"jobs"
             score:"2.7"
           },
           {
             name:"facility"
             score:"4.2"
           },
           {
             name:"location"
             score:"4.7"
           }
         ]
         },
         ...
        ]
```

I would like to filter the array scores and return the following structure for each object in the array of companies

```
        companies = [
         {
         about:"Dolore occaecat cillum."
         address:"Manhattan Court, 445"
         city:"Brecon, Massachusetts"
         email:"info@ziggles.info"
         id:0
         name:"Ziggles"
         phone:"+1 (944) 472-2911"
         postal_code:33
         project_number:2016823
         scores:[
           {
             name:"jobs"
             score:"2.7"
           }
          ]
         },
         ...
        ]
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: *return the one with the biggest score point for "jobs"* will that be an object or an array containing just one item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first filter, then sort the array

```js
// remove extra details of companies to make code easier to read
companies = [
         {
     
         id:0,
 
    
         scores:[
           {
             name:"jobs",
             score:"2.7"
           },
           {
             name:"facility",
             score:"4.2"
           },
           {
             name:"location",
             score:"4.7"
           }
         ],
         },
           {
      
         name:"C2",
    
         scores:[
           {
             name:"jobs",
             score:"3"
           },
           {
             name:"facility",
             score:"4.2"
           },
           {
             name:"location",
             score:"4.7"
           }
         ]
         },
           {
  
         name:"C3",
     
         scores:[
         
           {
             name:"facility",
             score:"4.2"
           },
           {
             name:"location",
             score:"4.7"
           }
         ]
         },
         
        ]
        

 // if companies is a big array you might want to combine filter an
const newCompanies = companies.filter(comp => comp.scores.find(scoreObject => scoreObject.name === 'jobs')).sort((comp1, comp2) =>  parseFloat(comp2.scores.find(scoreObject => scoreObject.name === 'jobs').score, 10) - parseFloat(comp1.scores.find(scoreObject => scoreObject.name === 'jobs').score,10))
console.log(newCompanies) // first element will have highest score
```